# Symfony2 passed argument is null

Tags: symfony, null, arguments

I'm building a CRM system and I faced a weird problem I'm unable to solve. When I try to create a new CustomerCase entity, I want to assign a CaseState entity for it, so this is what I do in the createAction of CustomerCaseController.php:

```
    $caseStateId = $request->request->get('caseState_id');
    $caseState = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('HSWAshaBundle:CaseState')->findOneById($caseStateId);
    $entity  = new CustomerCase();
    $entity->setCaseState($caseState);
...... etc.....
```

Everything works just fine until the **setCaseState** method. After running setCaseState, I get the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to HSW\AshaBundle\Entity\CustomerCase::setCaseState() must be an instance of HSW\AshaBundle\Entity\CaseState, null given, called in /home/webuser/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php on line 538 and defined in /home/webuser/Symfony/src/HSW/AshaBundle/Entity/CustomerCase.php line 843
```

The weird part is that $caseState really is a CaseState object (because for example $caseState->getName() works and gives me the correct name for the selected CaseState). **For some mind blowing reason it just turns null** when I use the setCaseState method. If I do $entity->setCaseState($customerStateObject->getId()), I get the same error message, but this time null changes to integer.

The CustomerCase has a manyToOne relationship with CaseState.

This works just fine if I use the formBuilder's add() method and skip all this manual work, but since I'm using a very specific auto-populating jQuery dropdown for selecting the CaseState from a nested tree structure, I had to manually add the dropdown and read it with $request->request->get().

I've been fighting with this part for almost three days now and would greatly appreciate every help I can get with this!

Comment: Does `$caseStateId` have the proper value ? did you try casting it to (int) ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got it to work! The reason was $request was missing some parameters because the twig template was missing form_rest(form). After adding that, everything started to work. Thank you!